# failed to create an iconphoto with image "pyimage1"

Tags: python, tkinter

I really have no idea with this isn't working. Since it's a tkinter error, I have no idea how to fix it. Help is needed.

Code:

```
from urllib import request
from tkinter import *
import urllib
import base64

user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.51 Safari/537.36"
url = "https://redstoner.me/downloads/gigashitfiles/gigashit.ico"
headers = {"User-Agent" : user_agent,} 
request = urllib.request.Request(url,None,headers)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
response.close()
b64pic = base64.encodebytes(response.read())
image = PhotoImage(data=b64pic)
window.iconphoto(True, image)
```

Output:

```
 File"myfilepath", line 19, in <module>
    window.iconphoto(True, image)
  File "C:\Users\panag\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2154, in wm_iconphoto
    self.tk.call('wm', 'iconphoto', self._w, "-default", *args)
_tkinter.TclError: failed to create an iconphoto with image "pyimage1"
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is the issue but some of the chars in the response are at symbols (@), percent symbols and parenths, and other characters that may be leading to an issue here. When you use base64.encodebytes() to encode this data the result is an empty byte string, probably indicating this data is not being converted to what you expect it to be.

Comment: Here are the first hundred chars of the value of response.read(): "b'\\x00\\x00\\x01\\x00\\x06\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x01\\x00 \\x00\\x15\\x07\\x00\\x00f\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x80\\x80\\x00\\x00\\x01\\x00 \\x00(\\x08\\x01\\x00{\\x07\\x00\\x00@@\\x00\\x00\\x01\\x00 \\x00(B\\x00\\x00\\xa3\\x0f\\x01\\x0000\\x00\\x00\\x"

Comment: I got `b''` instead because `response.read()` is called after `response.close()`.  Also `tkinter.PhotoImage()` does not support `.ico` format.

Comment: @acw1668 Thank you all for the comment, I got it working and was wondering if you know how to get the "photoimage" to appear in the taskbar too